# Effect-size of a fractional factorial design?

Tags: experiment-design, effect-size, treatment-effect, fractional-factorial

Let us assume I conduct an experiment, in which the participants perform four different tasks, getting a tool support or not. We measure the time to complete each task, either with the support of a new tool or not (indicated by the boolean value in brackets in the following table).

The result could look like:

| Participant | Task 1 | Task 2 | Task 3 | Task 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 s (true) | 24 s (false) | 9 s (true) | 18 s (false) |
| 2 | 28 s (false) | 14 s (true) | 9 s (false) | 18 s (true) |
| 3 | 29 s (true) | 49 s (false) | 11 s (true) | 22 s (false) |
| 4 | 98 s (false) | 49 s (true) | 4 s (false) | 2 s (true) |

As you can see, for complexity reasons, we cannot measure the times for all task for all participants with and without the tool-supported; we are missing half of the entries in the table by design.

I started with normalizing the times per task and per treatment (with or without tool-support) and apply a t-test to show the effect of the tool-support. However, this feels wrong although I cannot point the finger to the problem. Isn't it a fractional factorial design with a systematic subset (fraction) of the experimental runs of a full factorial design? How could I show the effect of the tool-support?

Comment: Fit a multiple linear regression model?